# document.onkeyup ported to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm porting some old Javascript to jQuery:

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    if (!event) window.event;
    ...
}
```

this code works on all major browsers. My jQuery code looks like:

```
$(document).keyup = function (event) {
    ...
}
```

however this code is not working (the function is never triggered at least in IE7/8). Why? How to fix?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [jQuery API](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keyup) is different:

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    ...
});
```

jQuery.keyup is a function which takes as an argument the callback. The reason behind it is to let us assign multiple keyup (or whatever) events.

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    alert('foo');
});

$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    alert('bar');
});
```

There's also keyup() without an argument, which will trigger the keyup event associated with the respective element.